# Merge columns within a dataframe that is very wide in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(ID=letters[1:10],
             A1=rnorm(10),A2=rnorm(10,1,3),
             B1=rnorm(10),B2=rnorm(10,1,3),
             C1=rnorm(10),C2=rnorm(10,1,3),
             D1=rnorm(10),D2=rnorm(10,1,3),
             E1=rnorm(10),E2=rnorm(10,1,3))
```

What I wanted is to add up `*1` and `*2` columns from A-E. It seems easy to realize but the key issue for my case is the df is very wide and I prefer to not type A-E with a desired output with column names `c("ID", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `split` the column names of 'df' except the first one ('ID') by the substring of the column names created by removing the numeric part (using `sub`), loop through the `list` elements with `sapply`, subset the columns of 'df' based on the index, get the `rowSums` and `cbind` with the first column (`df[1]`)

```
cbind(df[1], sapply(split(names(df)[-1], sub("\\d+", "", names(df)[-1])),
                              function(x) rowSums(df[x])))
# ID          A          B          C           D           E
#1   a  4.1117697  1.2115690  1.0652486 -0.09345402  3.98627575
#2   b  1.8492640 -0.1031894  0.7064425 -6.42983008  3.03047128
#3   c  3.7610227  2.6593725 -0.3940077  3.68400819  1.34553517
#4   d  1.4025565  2.9055092  7.2747628 -2.14617767 -0.23934168
#5   e -0.5382357  2.8397040  1.5306490 -2.13581708  4.86147078
#6   f  8.0758044  1.3792275  4.4263032  4.38024275 -0.46899680
#7   g  2.9544676  3.4995400 -4.0491432  0.59389076  8.65883799
#8   h -6.1649127  0.9676380  2.2871859 -2.60914891  6.03301337
#9   i  2.4172149 -1.0560249  2.1515278  2.46617791 -0.03303266
#10  j -0.8640362  1.1124019  1.5644556  2.63341060 -0.93045508
```